# Get range of 0 value based on first column

Tags: awk

I have this file

```
1    1    1
1    2    5
1    3    0
1    4    0
1    5    0
1    6    3
1    7    4
1    8    0
1    9    0
2    1    0
2    2    0
2    3    1
2    4    0
3    1    1
3    2    1
3    3    2
```

I want to print the lines for each first and last "0" line in the third column. Even if a 0 line has not zero line before and after , I need to double up this line. In order to get this :

```
1    3    0
1    5    0
1    8    0
1    9    0
2    1    0
2    2    0
2    4    0
2    4    0
```

I do

```
awk '
function print_prev() {
   if (prevline) print prevline
   prevline=""
}
$3!=0 { print_prev() }
$3==0 { if (prev3!=$3) print
      prevline=$0
      }
      { prev3=$3 }
END   { print_prev() }
' test.txt


1    3    0
1    5    0
1    8    0
2    2    0
2    4    0
2    4    0
```

But I need to output this based on the first column. I mean if the value in the first column changes and the  value is still "0" in the third column, I need to create a new range because of the 1st colum change. My code prints from the first to the last 0 line here :

```
1    8    0
2    2    0
```

But I would like to get :

```
1    8    0
1    9    0
2    1    0
2    2    0
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```bash
$ cat tst.awk
$NF || ($1 != prev) {
    prt()
    prev = $1
}
!$NF {
    if ( !cnt++ ) {
        beg = $0
    }
    end = $0
}
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( cnt ) {
        print beg ORS end
        cnt = 0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1    3    0
1    5    0
1    8    0
1    9    0
2    1    0
2    2    0
2    4    0
2    4    0
```